# Win32 version of fcntl(..., F_DUPFD. ...)?

Tags: winapi, fcntl

Win32 has `_open()`, `_open_osfhandle()`, etc. - but is there a Win32 version of `fcntl(..., F_DUPFD. ...)` which can duplicate a given file descriptor, and uses the lowest available file descriptor GREATER OR EQUAL than the given arg (e.g. this is NOT Win32 `_dup()` or `_dup2()`!!)?

I'm basically looking for the Linux/Solaris/Illumos implementation of this `fcntl()` function for Win32, or emulation code:

```
   F_DUPFD (int)
          Duplicate the file descriptor fd using the lowest-numbered
          available file descriptor greater than or equal to arg.
          This is different from dup2(2), which uses exactly the
          file descriptor specified.
```

Comment: `_open` and cousins are provided by a compatibility layer in the Universal CRT on windows. Native OS `HANDLE`s operate differently and the value of the `HANDLE` is considered opaque so that functionality isn't needed. There is no guarantee on Win32 that `HANDLE`s will be allocated sequentially. So there are many ways to do `fcntl` like things on Win32, but not the one you're asking for to duplicate to the lowest possible handle. That's just not a thing.

Comment: As Mgetz says, file descriptors are a fiction on Windows.  Whatever meaning might be implied by one fd being numerically higher than another doesn't hold on Windows.